# Как отправить сообщение с телефона на сервер на компьютере? Python

Tags: python, android, python-3.x, сокет

Нужно отправить текст или текстовый файл с телефона на сервер на компьютере. Сервер - это код на Python использующий библиотеку socket. Как это реализовать? ОС телефона - Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Напиши скрипт на Python, который будет отправлять сообщения/файлы на твой сервер (или как тебе нужно)
2. Скачай Termux и запусти скрипт на телефоне

Подробнее о Termux можешь посмотреть [тут](https://zen.yandex.ru/media/id/599a6bed58166942bb883152/zapusk-python-skriptov-na-android-s-pomosciu-termux-599b01991410c30133daaff5)

Answer (score 2):

это можно сделать используя приложение Termux.
Команды для установки питона:

```
pkg up
pkg install python(3)
```

Затем скачайте скрип клиента(на питоне) к себе на телефон далее перейдите в папку
со скриптом cd имя папки.

```
python3 имя скрипта.py
```

и используйте его как на пк. ссылка на [termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux&hl=ru) в гугл плей